# Excel Dynamic Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am sure this is really simple but cannot get it to work. I am trying to do some conditional formatting on a sheet that over time will have additional columns added to it. I want the formatting to be there before hand since the data is being added via VBA and the person using the spreadsheet are not Excel experts.

What I have is a column with numbers in. When a new column is entered I want to compare the value with the value in the previous column and then colour the cell accordingly. I can do this for a single cell with for example "=D2>C2".

I want to be able to write the rules in cell D2 comparing it with cell C2 and then have the rules apply across the area D2:DDD300. So for example cell N19 will compare itself to cell M19.

I thought I could use the "Applies to" box but that does not work. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: How is it not working? Can you include an image of the Rules Manager Dialog Box, so we can see/copy what you did?

Comment: Hi @MarcoVos it is still applying the rules based on D2 vs C2. So if M19 was 3 and N19 was 5 I would expect N19 to be red but it is being coloured based on the difference between D2 and C2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this now appears to be working. Not sure what I did differently but deleted all the rules and then set them up again. The only thing I did different was to initially do it for just the 1 cell, then expanded it out to the row when I knew it was working, then finally the whole area.

Sorry to have wasted peoples time

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work. It does for me. Maybe this helps:

[image]